# How to groupby in pandas dataframe by one column only if other column value is not same

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
df
     ID  first    last
0   123    Joe  Thomas
1   456  James   Jonas
2   675  James   Jonas
3   457  James  Thomas
```

I want an output as follows:

```
{'Thomas': [123, 457], 'James':[675, 457]}
```

such that for all the rows where `'last'` is same but `'first'` is different or where `'first'` is same but `'last'` is different, get IDs for those.

I'm trying to do it as follows:

```
    for i in zip(df['ID'], df['first'], df['last']):
...     last.setdefault(i[2],[])
...     first.setdefault(i[1],[])
...     last[i[2]].append(i[0])
...     first[i[1]].append(i[0])
```

with which I get the output as:

```
>>> first
{'James': [456, 675, 457], 'Joe': [123]}
>>> last
{'Thomas': [123, 457], 'Jonas': [456, 675]}
```

But this only groups by either 'first' or 'last' and does not check that the other one should not be same. How do I get the desired output?

UPDATE:

dropped duplicates as:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['first', 'last'], take_last=False)
```

ANSWER:

Did it this way. Not sure if this is correct. Any suggestions?

```
new_d = pd.melt(df.sort_values('ID').drop_duplicates(['first','last']),'ID').groupby('value').ID.apply(list).to_dict()

low_d = {k:v for k, v in new_d.items() if len(v)!=1}
```

Comment: drop duplicated first

Comment: Closest to a pandas solution I could concoct. It's not even a sure thing: `df1 = pd.melt(df.groupby('first').apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates(['last'], keep='last')), 'ID', ['first', 'last'], 'denoms', 'names'); df1[df1.names.duplicated(keep=False)].groupby('names')['ID'].apply(list).to_dict()`.

Comment: What version of python and pandas are you using? The code in your update suggests you are using a different version than what @Abdou is using, which is why you may not be able to appreciate his comment answer... If you are able to answer your question then please post it as an answer to your question and accept it. Your request for improvement suggestions will probably be more successful in codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Building off of the answer that @Abdou provided in the comment, I can confirm this works in Python version 2.7.13 using Pandas version 0.20.1, and also in Python version 3.6.2 using Pandas version 0.20.3:

```
from __future__ import division, print_function
import pandas as pd
import sys


def main():

    print("python version is: %s" % sys.version)
    print("pandas version: %s" % pd.__version__)

    df = pd.DataFrame(data={'first': ['Joe','James','James','James'],
                            'last': ['Thomas','Jonas','Jonas','Thomas'],
                            'ID': [123, 456, 675, 457]})

    grouped = df.groupby('first')\
                .apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates(['last'], keep='last'))

    melted = pd.melt(grouped, 'ID', ['first', 'last'], 'denoms', 'names')

    result = melted[melted.names.duplicated(keep=False)]\
                .groupby('names')['ID']

    print(result.apply(list).to_dict())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```